# A single file for my pgfplot data

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a tikzpicture with many lines of varying sizes. 
I decided to separate the data from the plotting logic by creating a pgftable with all my data the selecting the data rows that I want to plot. This works fine and leads to clean tikzpicture source, but it forces me to pad my data with `nan` values which bloat my file size and hence the table loading time and compilation time. I can of course separate my data into multiple files, but I prefer to manage a single data source.

Is this possible to do without padding my data with nan values?

MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

% My file is much bigger than this so padding my data
% with nans becomes untenable. 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
  X1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  Y1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  X2 1 2 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
  Y2 1 1 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

  \pgfplotstabletranspose[input colnames to={X1}, colnames from={X1}]{\loadedtable}{data.txt}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot table [x=X1, y=Y1] {\loadedtable};
      \addplot table [x=X2, y=Y2] {\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a proper column separator like a comma. Then you can have empty cells by simply placing the commas right next to each other. You just have to tell `pgfplotstable` what column separator you are using via the `col sep` option.

With that method your MWE would look like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

% My file is much bigger than this so padding my data
% with nans becomes untenable. 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
  X1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
  Y1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
  X2,1,2,,,,,,,,
  Y2,1,1,,,,,,,,
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}
  \pgfplotstabletranspose[input colnames to={X1}, colnames from={X1}]{\loadedtable}{data.txt}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot table [x=X1, y=Y1] {\loadedtable};
      \addplot table [x=X2, y=Y2] {\loadedtable};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It's not perfect as you still have to place all the commas but it's certainly better than the solution with the `nan` approach.